# How can we check if a date falls between today's hours?

Tags: apex, trigger, formula

How can we check if a record was modified between today's date between 10am-3pm?

My goal is to update any records that has been modified between 10am-3pm or basically anytime before 3pm. Would I need to use the business class?

```
public static Boolean BusinessHours.isWithin(String businessHoursId, Datetime targetDate)
```

I read this:  https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexcode.meta/apexcode/apex_classes_businesshours.htm

But not sure how to set it up since i don't want the default business hours. I'm trying to set up my own technically.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you don't have to use `BusinessHours` class. It is used to work with busienss hours defined for your org. In order to detect if record have been edited in specified date range use [Datetime](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexcode.meta/apexcode/apex_methods_system_time.htm#apex_methods_system_time) and [Time](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexcode.meta/apexcode/apex_methods_system_time.htm#apex_methods_system_time) classes

```
Lead ld = [
    select Id, LastModifiedDate
    from Lead
    limit 1
];

Time timeStart = Time.newInstance(10, 0, 0, 0); / 10 am
Time timeEnd = Time.newInstance(15, 0, 0, 0); / 3 pm

DateTime dtStart = DateTime.newInstance(Date.today(), timeStart);
DateTime dtEnd = DateTime.newInstance(Date.today(), timeEnd);

if(ld.LastModifiedDate >= dtStart && ld.LastModifiedDate < dtEnd){
    System.debug('record was changed in specified datetime range');
}
```